# Is it appropriate to use GC.AddMemoryPressure to trigger more frequent Runtime Callable Wrapper (RCW) finalization?

Tags: c#, com, garbage-collection

My .NET application is using very high numbers of RCWs in a very short period of time (thousands of RCWs in less than a second). I am able to gauge this behavior with the following performance counters:
 - Process -> Handle Count
 - .NET CLR Memory -> # of Sink Blocks in use

We have correctly implemented IDisposable wrapper objects around the RCWs; we call Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject on the various RCWs, and in the appropriate order.

According to [this blog post](http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/09/10/runtime-callable-wrapper-internals-and-common-pitfalls/), the COM object underlying an RCW is not actually cleaned up until the RCW is finalized.

Is it appropriate to use GC.AddMemoryPressure to force the GC to clean up our RCWs more quickly to prevent out of memory errors?

Comment: It is not appropriate, you do not have a good way to call RemoveMemoryPressure().  That requires a finalizer, an RCW already has one and you can't modify it.  If you are convinced that you call FRCO correctly then you simply need to dispose quicker :)

Comment: Hans, we wrap every RCW in our own C# object, each of which has a destructor. Would it be appropriate to add memory pressure in our C# wrapper object? We also implement Dispose of course, which calls Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject. Since we have a destructor, we can remove the memory pressure.

Comment: If you are convinced that you call FRCO correctly then you should not run out of memory nor need the help from the GC.  You only get OOM when you are actually out of memory, using AddMemoryPressure does not stop that..  If you are not convinced, and you shouldn't, then you are much better off reference-counting the objects you create and call GC.Collect() at a certain value.

Comment: @HansPassant Do you want to post that comment as an answer? That was a good idea about keeping a count and calling GC.Collect+WaitForPendingFinalizers periodically.

Answer (score 2):

You should maintain an explicit managed reference to each COM object, and call [Marshal.ReleaseComObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.releasecomobject%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) as soon as the COM object is no longer needed.

> This method is used to explicitly control the lifetime of a COM object used from managed code. You should use this method to free the underlying COM object that holds references to resources in a timely manner or when objects must be freed in a specific order.

Note that using "double dots" causes the runtime to create hidden managed references, e.g. a common pattern in Excel:

```
Worksheet sheet = excelApp.Worksheets.Open(sheetName);
```

creates a hidden managed object that wraps Worksheets.  The preferred method would be

```
Worksheets sheets = excelApp.Worksheets; 
Worksheet sheet = sheets.Open(sheetName);
```

You would call Marshal.ReleaseComObject on each of those managed variables, in the reverse order they were created.

If you do have hidden references to COM objects, the only reliable method to dispose of them that I have seen is

```
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Thanks, Eric. As I said above, we're already using Marshal.ReleaseComObject. And we are careful about "double dots" -- i.e. we make sure to release each managed reference. We're also aware that GC.Collect + GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers cleans them up. But my question is whether using GC.AddMemoryPressure is appropriate in this case so that we don't have to manually call GC.Collect + GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers.